# Dr Jonathan Crane pronounciation of Ras Alghoul was not correct

Tags: dialogue, batman-begins

In *Batman Begins*, Jonathan Crane 'Cillian Murphy' in his forced by Batman response to the question of the latter about the responsible for  planning to destroy Gotham he pronounced Rasa ghul rather than Ras Alghoul. Was he mistaken, careless or was it in purpose?

Rass means the head in arabic and al ghoul means the monster (رأس الغول). Ra's al ghul:  head of the monster. It should be written and pronounced Ra'ss al ghool.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-DC-Comics-settle-on-one-pronunciation-of-Ras-al-Ghul

Comment: Rass means the head in arabic and al ghoul means the monster (رأس الغول). Ra's al ghul:  head of the monster. It should be writen and pronoused Ra'ss al ghool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ra's al Ghul (Arabic: راس الغول‎ Raʾs al-Ġūl; "Ghoul's Head" or "Demon's Head") and if we follow the arabic origins it should be Rahz/Rah-us (I understand, I'm no linguist).

However, I understand that the character's creator was Jewish and the pronunciation of Ra's in *Hebrew* is Raysh/Raish and that is used sometimes.

The pronunciation of **Ra's al Ghul** has never really been clarified with the DC universe and some shows have used Rahz (the traditional pronunciation) and others Raysh (*Arrow* actually used both **at the same time** quite effectively).

However, in *Batman Begins* the pronunciation sticks to "Rahz"...and in the clip you refer to Crane, it seems to me, uses it *consistently* with the rest of the movie.

> Batman: "Who are you working for?"
>
> Crane: "Ra's [Rahz], Ra's [Rahz] ]Al Ghul"

NOT: "Rasa Ghul" as you suggest.

Comment: I specially like Batman's harch voice

Comment: As for those who did not like my question. May they find a better one. Huh

Comment: Why does Arkham City pronounce it so differently? They call him Raysh

Comment: That's covered in the answer.